# Problemas na instalação do Ionic Framework

Tags: node.js, cmd, prompt, ionic

Sou iniciante com o framework [Ionic](http://ionicframework.com/) e estou com um problema ao tentar fazer a instalação.

Recentemente tive que formatar meu computador e agora não estou conseguindo instalar novamente o framework. Quando executo o comando `npm install -g ionic` surge o erro que vocês poderão ver na imagem abaixo.

Tenho o Nodejs instalado e gostaria de saber se alguém ai já teve esse problema e como posso solucioná-lo. Aparentemente é um problema com o proxy, mas já tentei o que eu sabia e não adiantou.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Desde já agradeço pela atenção de vocês.
Obrigado.

Comment: Parabéns pela medalha `Esqueceram de Mim`

Comment: I answer in another post.
Check it.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/32079988/5240528

Comment: Você instalou cordova ?

Comment: Isso já aconteceu comigo quando utilizava rede corporativa, com restrições de acesso e configurações de proxy. Resolvi conectando em outra rede e baixando os pacotes.

Answer (score 1):

Você tem que ter instalado antes:

- O Python: https://www.python.org/downloads/
- O Git: https://git-scm.com/download/win
- Mesmo não usando, é bom instalar o https://www.visualstudio.com/pt-br/vs/community/ com todas as suas atualizações
- JDK - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/pt/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Ai, você roda este comando.